# AssertionError: Element odoo has extra content: data, line 4

Tags: odoo-10, odoo-9, odoo-view

I am using Odoo 11 and am trying to get a report working. I have this code working in Odoo 9 but cant see where the problem is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding= "utf-8"?>

<odoo>
    <data>

         <t t-name="ds_repair.qweb_ds_repair_template2">


            <t t-foreach ="docs" t-as="o">

                    <div class="page" style="text-align: center;">
                        <div class="oe_structure"/>


                        <span><img height="44" width="auto" src="data:image/png;base64,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" /></span>
                        <span style="font-size:24px;"><strong><span t-field="o.x_partner_id"/></strong></span>
                        <span style="font-size:18px;"><strong><span t-field="o.x_partner_id.mobile"/></strong></span>

                    </div>

        </t>
            </t>

    </data>
</odoo>
```

Comment: you need to define template tag

Answer (score 0):

**

> If you are trying to create a report view then this will solve the
>   issue

**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding= "utf-8"?>

<odoo>
    <data>

        <template id="ds_repair.qweb_ds_repair_template2">
            <t t-call="web.html_container">


            <t t-foreach ="docs" t-as="o">

                    <div class="page" style="text-align: center;">
                        <div class="oe_structure"/>


                        <span><img height="44" width="auto" src="data:image/png;base64,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" /></span>
                        <span style="font-size:24px;"><strong><span t-field="o.x_partner_id"/></strong></span>
                        <span style="font-size:18px;"><strong><span t-field="o.x_partner_id.mobile"/></strong></span>

                    </div>

        </t>
            </t>
</template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```